# Fluentd logger for .net MVC application

Tags: .net, logging, nlog, fluentd

Had anybody used fluentd logger in .NET MVC application.

they do have .NET data source(NLog) at the moment

http://www.fluentd.org/datasources

But looks like its not widely used, anybody had any experience of integrating fluentd with .NET application?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the package on Nuget is the latest (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.Fluentd/), but it doesn't seem active as it's build against NLog 2 while NLog 4 is released last year. Although it probably still work as there are no breaking changes in the core logging API between NLog 1 and 4.